# How can I connect UIPickerView in my app using Interface Builder?

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I am developing a iPhone (Utility Application) app using Xcode and Interface Builder (IB). I am using a UIPickerView in my app using IB. But I dont know how to connect UIPickerView in my app. Its show a empty picker. How can I connect data in UIPickerView? Plz tell me details...

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement the UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate protocols to get data into your picker and know when the user makes a selection. Then in IB make the connection from the picker to the object that implements these protocols.

Comment: Take a look at the LocateMe example